# UWP Toast Notification xml schema button font size

Tags: xml, uwp, toast

I have a UWP toast notification xml schema. I have a button in it and the text is getting removed if the length of text is more.

How can i change the font size of button text in Toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Andrew from the notifications team at Microsoft.

As a developer, you can't control the font size within buttons on toasts. 
The font size is picked to be consistent and usable across all apps.

If you share your payload and your scenario, we can suggest alternatives for you to try.

Thanks!
Andrew